# Coredumps are not generated when the process is running in the background

Tags: debugging, gdb

My program is written in C/C++ and compiled using -ggdb flag. And want to see corefiles are being generated.

I bring up the program from the below script.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Starts the application.
#
NAME=my_app
test -x /usr/bin/my_app || exit 0

start() {
        echo -n "Starting my app "
        $NAME > /dev/null 2>&1 &
        sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern='/var/core/%e.%p.%h.%t.core'
        ulimit -c unlimited
        echo "OK"
}
```

For testing I added the below crashing statement.

```
  char z[100];
  std::strncpy(z, NULL, 100);
```

I could generate corefiles when my application is run from the shell (bash) or even when it's run in the background using '&'. **But when it's brought up from the script above, the corefiles are not generated.**

What am I doing wrong here? Or is there any other way to sort this out?
Thanks

Comment: your script _first_ runs your app , then sets core file location

Comment: Languages your program is writren in are irrelevant. The kernel doesn't care.

Comment: change order of statements. "ulimit -c unlimited" should be 1st statement, then it should start work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when it's brought up from the script above, the corefiles are not generated.

The application will likely produce a core dump *if* your `ulimit -c` is set to `unlimited` *before* running the script.

Your script does 3 things:

1. run the application in background
2. set core pattern
3. set `ulimit -c unlimited`.

Note that step 3 is *completely* pointless: it only affect processes that you create *after* you set the new limit (in your script, that's just the `echo "OK"`).

What you want to do is perform steps 2, 3 and *then* 1. When performed in that order, `ulimit -c unlimited` will actually affect your application (which inherits the limit from current shell at the moment it is created).